# Ways to detect TCP connection resets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, java-8

I have made a small telnet-like application, and currently the only way i know if two sockets cannot communicate is when a `SocketException` is thrown with the message "Connection reset" (when i poll for input). It doesn't produce a problem in my application however, since i can catch the exception, but is there a way for me to test if the connection has been reset before i poll for input, or is catching the exception the only way? Methods have to be a part of the Java API (no 3. parties).

No methods of the `Socket` class seems to be able to answer this, and i haven't been able to find anything on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to detect anything wrong with a TCP connection is to write to it or read from it.